# PySimpleGUI: How to get size of an image

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have an image viewer that shows the selected image. However I have different sizes of images and I would like to access the selected image size in order to have a fixed GUI. Otherwise GUI resizes and images are not showing properly. Is there any way to see the size of an image? After I get the image size I am thinking of subsampling according to its size. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `PIL.Image.open` to open an image file, then get the size by its attribute `size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open('test.png') as im:
    size = im.size
    print(size)
```

Here is a way using PIL Image package.